# Drag Mouse and Move Borderless Form Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been looking for a little while for some code that would allow the user to 'click and drag' to move around a borderless form. I have achieved this in VB.Net and C# in Windows Forms, and have I believe, done it in Excel historically (although I cannot remember the code). I cannot seem to work out the translations into Access VBA, primarily because the 'left' method cannot be applied to a Form object in a Private Sub (I think?):

```
Me.Left
```

Without this, I'm struggling to translate the code, so is there another way, perhaps with Windows API calls or just Form events to make this happen? I'd really like to exhaust the possibilities as Borderless Forms look so nice!

Any help hugely appreciated.

Here is the VB.Net version that works:

```
Dim dragForm As Boolean
Dim xDrag As Integer
Dim yDrag As Integer

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    dragForm = True
    xDrag = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
    yDrag = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If dragForm Then
        Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - yDrag
        Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - xDrag
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    dragForm = False 
End Sub
```

Here is my attempt to re-write this so far:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Dim xx As Long
Dim yy As Long

xx = Me.Left + X - xDrag
yy = Me.Top + Y - yDrag
Me.Left = xx
Me.Top = yy
moveFrm = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Dim xx As Long
Dim yy As Long

If moveFrm = True Then
     xx = Me.Left + X - xDrag
     yy = Me.Top + Y - yDrag
     Me.Left = xx
     Me.Top = yy
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    moveFrm = True
    xDrag = X
    yDrag = Y

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit broad. If the question is just: what's the equivalent of `Form.Top` and `Form.Left` in Access I can answer that. But I won't go creating a VB.Net application with the provided code, creating an Access application, and testing if they behave the same with some adjustments.

Comment: Thanks @ErikvonAsmuth - I only included the code in the question to show what I had tried so far. Essentially, for Access VBA, I'm just after a way to be able to drag and move a borderless form.

Comment: Use windows release capture and send measage API. Also check out [this](https://github.com/krishKM/Modern-UI-Components-for-VBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the form position in Access, you need to use `.WindowLeft` and `WindowTop`.

To set the form position, you need to use `.Move`

`Form_MouseDown` and `Form_MouseUp` only register when you click on a form part that's not the detail section.

```
Dim moveFrm As Boolean
Dim xDrag As Long
Dim yDrag As Long


Private Sub Detail_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
Dim xx As Long
Dim yy As Long

xx = Me.WindowLeft + x - xDrag
yy = Me.WindowTop + y - yDrag
Me.Move xx, yy
moveFrm = False

End Sub

Private Sub Detail_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
Dim xx As Long
Dim yy As Long

If moveFrm = True Then
     xx = Me.WindowLeft + x - xDrag
     yy = Me.WindowTop + y - yDrag
     Me.Move xx, yy
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Detail_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)

    moveFrm = True
    xDrag = x
    yDrag = y

End Sub
```

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for your reply! The solution works, but if you have a lot of monitors stacked horizontally (3 4k Monitors in my case) the "Me.WindowLeft" maximum value is "32767" and once you surpass that on the x axis it will return a wrong number and the form will start flickering. One way to fix this will be to limit the maximum position to be "32767", but that's more bodging than an actual fix. Would be curious if you have another idea how to fix it more properly.

Comment: @GeorgeSmith Well, you need to adjust this with the methods of determining form position and moving the form I've shared previously with you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159690/7296893). Regarding the flickering/invisible form, note that this answer contains only simple adjustments of the code shared in the question, you'd do better to adjust the code shared by Jörg

Comment: I really didn’t want to go that route, hoping that there is an easier solution. I tried what you advised me to do in the other post and moved from “Form.Move” to the “MoveWindow” win32 API. Using the Form.hWnd property to get the ID of the form/window I wanted to move around. Furthermore, as I already dived into the win32 APIs, I also added the GetCursorPos API in win32 to determine the X,Y coordinates of my mouse cursor instead of the X,Y coordinates coming from the “MouseMove” function in Access. This will work perfectly if all monitors (in my case 3) are scaled equally (125%).

Comment: However, as my third monitor is scaled to 300% compared to the other two scaled at 125%, I noticed that when I moved the form/window to the monitor that is scaled at 300% the solution above doesn’t work very well as the window/form will kind of jump when the cursor goes close to the right end of the screen. I found out that the GetCursorPos Coordinate will jump from 6293 to 5069 on the X axis and as a result the window will kind of jump to the left and land on the 5069 coordinates. I would appreciate any advice of why this might be happening and any suggestions about a potential fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, Access just plain doesn't support large monitors, so pretty much anytime you want to position on a large single-monitor or multi-monitor setup, you need WinAPI. You should be able to adjust for DPI by using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor. You already know how to determine where monitors are on the virtual screen, by determining their scaling factor you could probably adjust for this jumpiness. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question with your best attempt.

Answer (score 3):

An optimization based on [Erik A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116147/360480): Still a bit simpler and you can see the window move while you're dragging it.

```
Dim moveFrm As Boolean
Dim xMouseDown As Long
Dim yMouseDown As Long

Private Sub Detailbereich_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    moveFrm = True
    xMouseDown = X
    yMouseDown = Y

End Sub

Private Sub Detailbereich_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    If moveFrm Then
        Me.Move Me.WindowLeft + X - xMouseDown, Me.WindowTop + Y - yMouseDown
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Detailbereich_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    moveFrm = False

End Sub
```

Note: In German the Detail section is "Detailbereich", just alter it for your local.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done like this:

```
Private Sub FormMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, Y As Single, _
    ByVal MouseAction As MouseAction)

' Move the form by dragging the title bar or the label upon it.

    ' WindowLeft and WindowTop must be within the range of Integer.
    Const TopLeftMax        As Single = 2 ^ 15 - 1
    Const TopLeftMin        As Single = -2 ^ 15

    ' Statics to hold the position of the form when mouse is clicked.
    Static PositionX        As Single
    Static PositionY        As Single
    ' Static to hold that a form move is enabled.
    Static MoveEnabled      As Boolean

    Dim WindowTop           As Single
    Dim WindowLeft          As Single

    ' The value of MoveEnable indicates if the call is from
    ' mouse up, mouse down, or mouse move.

    If MouseAction = MouseMove Then
        ' Move form.
        If MoveEnabled = True Then
            ' Form move in progress.
            If Button = acLeftButton Then
                ' Calculate new form position.
                WindowTop = Me.WindowTop + Y - PositionY
                WindowLeft = Me.WindowLeft + x - PositionX
                ' Limit Top and Left.
                If WindowTop > TopLeftMax Then
                    WindowTop = TopLeftMax
                ElseIf WindowTop < TopLeftMin Then
                    WindowTop = TopLeftMax
                End If
                If WindowLeft > TopLeftMax Then
                    WindowLeft = TopLeftMax
                ElseIf WindowLeft < TopLeftMin Then
                    WindowLeft = TopLeftMax
                End If
                Me.Move WindowLeft, WindowTop
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ' Enable/disable form move.
        If Button = acLeftButton Then
            ' Only left-button click accepted.
            'If MoveEnable = True Then
            If MouseAction = MouseDown Then
                ' MouseDown.
                ' Store cursor start position.
                PositionX = x
                PositionY = Y
                MoveEnabled = True
            Else
                ' MouseUp.
                ' Stop form move.
                MoveEnabled = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

and, for example:

```
Private Sub BoxTitle_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, Y As Single)

    ' Enable dragging of the form.
    Call FormMove(Button, Shift, x, Y, MouseDown)

End Sub
```

It's all in my article: [Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013+](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17684/Modern-Metro-style-message-box-and-input-box-for-Microsoft-Access-2013.html)

Full code is also at **GitHub**: [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox.git)

Comment: Thanks @Gustav - this article looks really interesting. How would I adapt this code to a form? I have copied the Private Enum from the article to make this compile, but without a titlebar, i'm not sure if this would work?

Comment: You could make the title bar the same colours as the background of the form. Or, perhaps, let the "title" bar/box fill most of the form. Note too, that normally the form body isn't dragable.