# ".MoveSize" or ".Move" for a popup form positioning

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created an on click button event, which is supposed to move my popup form to the top left corner of the screen. The function that I used was:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    DoCmd.MoveSize(0 ,0)
End Sub
```

I noticed that if my popup form is positioned on my second monitor it will send the popup form to the top left corner of my primary monitor.

Is there a way to send the form to the top left corner of whichever monitor the form is being opened in?

I tried a different idea where I will use a function to use the ".Move" property of the form. I came up with this:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Form.Move(0, 0)
End Sub
```

This didn't work either, as it seems that the "0, 0" coordinates are relative to wherever the Access Window is positioned on the screen and not the top left corner of the monitor.

Is this a limitation of Access VBA or is it doable using some other technique?

Comment: I read one thread indicating not setting for popup mode solved issue.

Comment: Is this just for you (and your monitor configuration)? Or for a multitude of users with various configurations (primary monitor left or right, possibly different resolutions etc.)? If the latter, better try to do it in a different way, that's no fun at all.

Comment: @June7, I have also seen a few comments suggesting that while researching the topic.

Comment: @Andre, it is just something I came up with to try and get more familiar with VBA. Therefore, no other users will be using the form. However, at the same time, I would rather the code to cover various configurations than just mine. I found an alternative that I can use negative values for x and y to push the form to the other monitor. That said I feel that is too much bodging than an actual solution.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/launch-vba-userforms-in-correct-window-with-dual-monitors I don't know if this applies to access the same way as to excel, but worth a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this seems trivial, unfortunately, it isn't, and we're going to need to use a fair amount of WinAPI. That makes it really hard for beginners.

We need a couple of things:

1. We need to be able to determine on which monitor the form is
2. We need to be able to determine where that monitor is in the "virtual screen" (think about positioning monitors relative to eachother)
3. We need to be able to determine the size of the current window in pixels
4. We need to be able to position the form on the "virtual screen".

For that, we need a couple of declarations. These are best kept on separate modules, but if you're 100% sure they will only be used on this form, they can go on the form too.

First, the type and value declarations:

```
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect
Public Type RECT
    left As Long
    top As Long
    right As Long
    bottom As Long
End Type

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-monitorinfo
Public Type MONITORINFO
    cbSize As Long
    rcMonitor As RECT
    rcWork As RECT
    dwFlags As Long
End Type

'Either look this one up by Googling, or create a C++ program that references winuser.h and print it
Public Const MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = &H2
```

Then, the function declarations:

```
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetMonitorInfoW Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hMonitor As LongPtr, ByRef lpmi As MONITORINFO) As Boolean

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow
Public Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow
Public Declare PtrSafe Function MoveWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal bRepaint As Boolean) As Boolean

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
```

And then, on the form, putting it all to work:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim mi As MONITORINFO
    Dim monitor As LongPtr
    Dim myrect As RECT
    'Get the current size and position of the window
    GetWindowRect Me.hWnd, myrect
    'Determine which monitor it is on
    monitor = MonitorFromWindow(Me.hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
    'Make sure WinAPI knows the size of the MONITORINFO struct we're working with
    mi.cbSize = LenB(mi)
    'Get the monitor info
    GetMonitorInfoW monitor, mi
    'Move the window to the top right, keep width and height equal to the current values
    MoveWindow Me.hWnd, mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top, myrect.right - myrect.left, myrect.bottom - myrect.top, True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, that's quite a lot more code and more complicated concepts than `DoCmd.MoveSize(0 ,0)`, but I do not know of a simpler approach. VBA doesn't really have any support for multiple monitors, so you'll often have to go to WinAPI to account for them.

Comment: Thank you deeply for the provided solution. It works like a charm. In addition, I really appreciate the comments that you have added, as well as the article links. It was quite helpful and interesting to read what each of the WinApi can do. Once again thank you  very much!